# isotope + lazyload makes elements reloading on filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-isotope, jquery-lazyload

The plugins are working well, on loading the default filter. The problem is when changing to another filter (using isotope) becouse the elements are showing well, but when scrolling, the elements are reloading, cousing a flash for any of them.

My js code is:

```
var $win = $(window);
var $container = $('.PortfolioItemContainer'),
$containerProxy = $container.clone().empty().css({ visibility: 'hidden' });
var $items = $('.PortfolioItemContainer .bgCover');

$items.lazyload({
    effect: "fadeIn",
    effectspeed: 1500,
    failure_limit: Math.max($items.length - 1, 0)
});

var grid = $('.PortfolioItemContainer').isotope({
    resizable: false,
    filter: '.all',
    masonry: { columnWidth: Math.floor( $('.PortfolioItemContainer').width() / 4)},
    onLayout: function() {
        $win.trigger("scroll");
    }
});
```

Screenshot on scrolling. Sometimes are re-loaded(flashing) 2,3, 4,.. elements
[image]

Any solutions are welcome

A similar example is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZnEhn/255/

Click on any other filter and scroll. The result is: some elements loaded from 'all' are shown, and new elements are now loaded so couse that random flashing

Comment: can u provide Fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnEhn/255/     Something like this. The default filter is 'all', but if you go to other section, (without scrolling on 'all'), there are some elements loaded from 'all', and other that are now loaded.